# nginx ssl proxy for one hostname only

Tags: nginx, ssl, http-headers

I want nginx to serve as a ssl proxy but for host: *"ssl.example.com"*

at the same time I want nginx to serve "nginx is ok" website for host: *"ssl-check.example.com"* (this is just example, please don't suggest any monitoring tools here)

for other hosts pointing to my IP I want to serve 404 or whatever.
- I don't care for certificate mismatch - so SNI is not what I want here.
- I don't want to use described as pitfall solution and use something like

```
if ($host != $server_name) {
root /var/www/errors/404
```

All these on single IP.

I have working ssl

```
server {
```

with server_name *ssl.example.com* - working as I want.

another ssl

```
server {
```

with server_name *ssl_check.example.com* - showing "nginx is ok"

and last server (also ssl) without server_name (or with "_" as name) which is supposed to serve 404 but it doesn't work...

**SOLVED**
My config using the solution looks now (and works) like:

1. server with "listen 443 ssl;" serving proxy
2. server with "listen 443 ssl;" serving "nginx is ok"
3. server with "listen 443 ssl default_server;" and with "location / return 404"

If this config can be in any way dangerous - don't hesitate to put me to shame.
Thans

Comment: Ok sorry about the answer, is the last server {} config block just http?

Comment: nope - last server is also ssl, http on this IP is served by varnish and it works on completely different host http header

Comment: I don't know... maybe in my case I should just make one ssl vhost and inside "server" just use "if + rewrite" in some way... I have never said that what I want to achieve is possible, I just ask you, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the default virtual host using the `default_server` option to the [`listen`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen) directive. If you don't set this nginx will choose the first `server` block with a matching `listen` directive.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    root /var/www/errors/404;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it was that simple :)